# Need help fixing keyboard. ZEB-K5000MW bluetooth

Tags: windows, ubuntu, keyboard, wireless-keyboard

Problem:

Whenever I type some keys it results in typing random characters.

```
4 -> T4

8 -> [8

0 -> 0]
```

and more.

What I've tried:

```
Re - pairing the keyboard to my laptop.

Draining it of charge and recharging it.
```

I primarily use this keyboard on my laptops with Ubuntu and windows OS.

Comment: Sounds like an electrical issue. Did it have contact with water?

Comment: Yours re-pairs with devices? What a pity I can't even do that. Is there a special procedure to re-pair? I've been trying for hours. And what if I disconnect one port and without removing pair I try to connect it with a new device, can't even do that. Any info will help.